# Attribute name not allowed on element meta at this point

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am having the error multiple times here

```
<meta name="description" content="Directus Media specialises in websites for small to medium businesses">​
```

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcrimsoninformatics.info%2Fdirectus%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Also the link attribute error:

I wrote :-

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/lib/essentials.css"/>
```

And it gives me error that link is missing required property.

Please help as i am new to HTML5.

Answer (score 9):

Between two `meta` tags, the one with `name="description"` and the one with `name="keywords"`, the page contains the bytes 0xE2 0x80 0x8B (and some whitespace). The page is being interpreted as UTF-8 encoded, but that sequence of bytes is malformed UTF-8 (does not represent any character). Apparently, the validator still interprets it as a data character. This causes the `head` element to be prematurely closed, and the rest is… well, not history, but a consequence of this confusion. The second of the `meta` tags is taken as being in the `body` part, and there special rules apply, making the tag invalid.

The real problem, anyway, is the presence of the bogus bytes 0xE2 0x80 0x8B. When they are removed, the page validates.

It is impossible to know, from outside, what produces those bytes. But they look suspiciously like a character encoding error, possibly causes by incorrectly performed UTF-8 encoding of some data that was already UTF-8 encoded, or something like that.

This was a tricky issue. I had to use Rex Swain’s [HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) to check the raw data of the [offending page](http://crimsoninformatics.info/directus/).

Comment: I would suggest better HTTP viewer https://www.httpdebugger.com/Tools/ViewHttpHeaders.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have UTF BOM removed from all source files. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

With (at least) Firefox, when it saves a html page on disk, it corrects tags.

So a way of correcting this kind of error is to load the offending page in Firefox, save it to disk and check how the browser corrected your meta tags in the saved version.

Answer (score -1):

Your complete link - Tag is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lib/essentials.css"/>
```

and your Meta-Tags:

```
<meta name="description" content="Directus Media specialises in websites for small to medium businesses" />​
<meta name="keywords" content="southport graphic design, liverpool web design, southport social media management" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

Be careful: I think you used wrong "" on your meta-Tags (keywords and viewport)