# Element link is missing required attribute property

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

i am using this in HTML5

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/loader.css"  media="all"/>
```

But w3c validator giving me this error:-

```
Element link is missing required attribute property.
```

Please help i am stucked with it,

My Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="en" class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->
<head>
<!-- The title of your site -->
    <title>Directus Media LTD</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- Always make sure to check the robots tag -->
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <meta name="description" content="Directus Media specialises in websites for small to medium businesses">​<meta name="keywords" content="southport graphic design, liverpool web design, southport social media management"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <script src="js/lib/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!-- Liquid Slider Master -->

    <!-- Essential stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/loader.css"  media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/lib/essentials.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/lib/ytplayer.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/lib/font-awesome.min.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/lib/magnific-popup.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/lib/jquery.bxslider.css"/>

    <!-- Main stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/colors/black.css"/>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
   </head>
<body>

<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Everything is according to standards. Please have a look on the code. I don't know why validator is  not passing my page.

Comment: Is your `<link>` inside the `<body>`? If yes, place it in the `<head>` at the top of the document

Comment: possible duplicate of [Element link is missing required attribute property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549726/element-link-is-missing-required-attribute-property)

Comment: its in head section, i am editing the question please have a look again

Comment: The problem is the same as your last question. You have invisible characters starting the `body` element earlier then you expect and the rules for what attributes are allowed on a link/meta element differ depending on if it is in the head or the body. Duplicate of [Attribute name not allowed on element meta at this point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464106/attribute-name-not-allowed-on-element-meta-at-this-point)

Comment: @Quentin is right, I written the meta tags by hand and everything is working. The `"description"` one has a problem, I don't know about the others.

Answer (score 0):

you can add **`property="stylesheet"`** in the `link` tag

Answer (score -2):

link tags don't need self closes. Remove that and try again.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: The question says it is HTML 5, so it is perfectly acceptable (albeit pointless) to put a `/` at the end of a link tag.

Comment: If you check HTML 5 Specification about that, You can see link tags have no self closed mode http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

Comment: I don't know why you think it should say "self closed mode", it is defined as having an empty content model. If you want to see how the `/` should be handled, then look at [the parsing rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead): Link elements "Acknowledge the token's self-closing flag" (which is added by having a `/` and causes a parse error to be thrown if it is **not** acknowledged).

Comment: As @Quentin says, both `<link />` and `<link>` are valid HTML5 markup.